# How to reinitialise the dataTable dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I created a datatable and added rows dynamically on selected option. So when each time changing the option, I need to reinitialise the dataTable. I put this piece of code inside the $("#selectOption").change(function(){}); because each time when option is changed I need to call this code.

```js
 $('#example').DataTable( {
    "scrollY":        "500px",
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "paging": true,
    "lengthChange": false,
    "searching": true,
    "ordering": true,
    "info": true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "autoWidth": true,
    "aLengthMenu": [[-1], ["All"]],
    });
    
   $('#example').dataTable().fnDestroy();
```

The above code is not working. Need Help

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you write your code inside $(document).ready(function()).??

Comment: see to it that jquery is loaded or not

Comment: @Akshaypadwal can u check it with teamviewer

Comment: @Sidharth look at the order in which your javascript files are placed in html place jquery on top of every other file.

Comment: @Akshaypadwal That and all is correct. If you dont mind, can u check it with teamviewer?

Comment: @Sidharth NO it would not be possible for me to check it with teamviewer

Comment: @Akshaypadwal It's urgent!!!

Comment: @Sidharth apologies i m at my work place cant help

Comment: @Akshaypadwal ok :)

Comment: @Sidharth see to it your files are in a correct order

Comment: @Sidharth atleast share your code snippet

Comment: @Akshaypadwal I made it correct. Anyway thanks for spending time for me :)

Answer (score 0):

**$ not defined error:**

```
put your jquery file on top of every other file into your Html.



var Table =    $('#example').DataTable( {
                    "scrollY":        "500px",
                    "scrollCollapse": true,
                    "paging": true,
                    "lengthChange": false,
                    "searching": true,
                    "ordering": true,
                    "info": true,
                    "bDestroy": true,
                    "autoWidth": true,
                    "aLengthMenu": [[-1], ["All"]],
        });
```

**every time you fetch a data from backend first clear table and then add datarow**

```
Table.fnClearTable();
Table.fnAddrow([//your data]);
```